# Warrior Mage Level and skill help

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I am making my character a Warrior Mage, I mainly use melee moves or melee/spells.  In leveling up what should I focus on? Should I go with Health Magicka and Stamina? and for my skills how many perks should I try to advance? I have so far gotten into the one handed combat tree and conjuration trees.  If I spec into any more is that bad? or are there any recommendations? I just don't want to end up hindering my character by picking too many things or the wrong things..Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is pretty much the same build that I've been using. I put a bit over half my total points into Magicka, most of the rest into Health, and very few into Stamina. I don't use many power attacks, and when I do, it's to finish the enemies off or stall for time while my Magicka is regenerating. It's working for me so far.

You will get enough perks to fill up 4 perk trees with room to spare, so don't worry about starting into another. I'm focusing on Conjuration, Destruction, Restoration, and One-handed, with a minor amount in Light Armor. Putting a point or two in a tree just to get a slight bonus isn't going to harm your chances of completing other trees.

Even if you completely focus on Conjuration, chances are you won't use **every** perk in that tree. You might focus on Atronachs over reanimating corpses, or you might not use bound weapons.

Just pick whatever perks you want and don't worry about it too much.

Comment: oo ok cool, thank you very much for that help :), one more question if I could, as for armor, would it be better if I went with light? because ive been using heavy. Or is that just something that either way is fine?  Thank you :)

Comment: @Tyr It's just up to personal preference. I like light armor better because it frees up more carrying capacity for other stuff, but heavy armor offers more protection. Whichever you choose is equally viable.

Comment: heavy armor isnt ideal for melee combat suprisingly, as the light armor 60 perk wind walker gives you a really good stamina boost.

Comment: @StrixVaria Awesome thank you again! I wish I could add you to something ot talk to you again you were very helpful :)

Comment: @StrixVaria I tried a few mins ago it told me I had to wait 3 mins, I am checking it now.

Comment: @Tyr Check out this site's chat room. There are always people to chat with.

Answer (score 3):

Here are my experiences in playing something similar.  In my playthrough, I am a rogue/mage, relying on sneaking, dual wield daggers, and destruction (mostly for the trap runes).

The most difficult aspects to consider:

- Splitting your level into all three stats is very difficult, meaning you won't excel at one or the other.  Heavy armor can offset the lack of health for a bit, but there's no getting around the lower stamina and/or lack of magika to cast lots of spells.  Its a bit easier for me as most of my spells are cast pre battle (buffs and traps) and I rely on melee in fights, but its still not an optimal situation until your level becomes much higher.
- I wouldn't worry too much about which perks to advance, but do try to maintain a healthy spread of all your skills.  This way, you don't level up nearly as fast and find yourself over leveled and facing enemies you shouldn't be facing yet.  You can keep the perks until you figure out what you want to place it in, but try to focus on no more than 4-5 trees.
- Going the blocking/shield route might be beneficial since you will have lower health than pure warriors.  Not to mention, the shield bash (along with any other knockback) can interrupt a dragon's flame attack.
- Conjuration is a great way to go as it summons additional meat shields for you, being able to dual cast a conjuration spell is a bonus as it'll make the summons last longer.  I wouldn't worry too much about lowering the cost for higher difficulty spells as this is a pre battle cast and you can recover the mana relatively quickly.

Comment: I wish that I could vote for two answers because your answer helped alot too.

Answer (score 1):

I'm also a quite new player but here's what I focus on:

- Conjuration for Flame Atronaches and the awesome bound bow mostly
- Destruction for... well, it's a mage, if I don't use destruction what would I use?
- Ice against warriors, Lighting against mages and Fire for quick massive damages. I suggest strongly to build perks on ice.
- A bit of restoration can be really useful.
- Also you'll need to build a bit one handed for when you're out of Magicka.

My favorite build is:

4 points in Magicka and 1 in Health; 0 in Stamina. Repeat that pattern forever as you level up: 4 points on Magicka, 1 point on Health.

Answer (score 0):

I focus on one handed (sword path only), block,heavy armor,destruction(shock only), a little bit on restoration (enough for stamina recovery spell perk), enchantment,smithing(only heavy armour and improve magical items) I don't commit all my perks into one tree except block and heavy armour. I only place them on things I think are important or just plain cool like the disintegrate perk for destruction. I'm not sure what to classify my character as but it's something like a shock mage-warrior or shock paladin whatever you want to call it nothing is more satisfying than spewing lightning wall all over the place and then hacking down your opponents with a enchanted sword and shield combo. Also the shield comes in handy while trying to heal yourself. You might want to keep your health/magica/stamina all in a balance because you can just enchant your armour on the area you feel like excelling in. And you can choose fire or frost path I was just telling you what I like ;)