# Warrior Mage skills help can't decide if Im doing this right

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Warrior Mage Level and skill help](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/36028/warrior-mage-level-and-skill-help)

Hi I have a Warrior Mage build and I have so far spread my skills for 4 specs I have put some in one-handed, destruction, conjuration, and heavy armor.  I am wondering if this is too many or if I can go into other trees for like blacksmithing because I want to make my own weapons and armors.  And I was thinking about switching to light armor cause everyone is telling me it is better than heavy for this build..should I do this? Please help me, and thank you soo very much for taking the time to read this.

Answer (score 0):

Focusing on a few skills rather than many will make the game easier if 1) you use these skills a lot and 2) they are required for combat.

Smithing is an alright choice though you have to make your combat skills have a higher priority.

Heavy armor affects movement speed, sneaking ability, and of course weighs more(without the perk). Though it may have a higher armor value it means nothing when going up against magic.

Light armor doesnt affect movement speed and sneaking ability as much and weighs less. the armor value isnt that noticable if you put perks into it and with smithing you can upgrade it to have decent armor values. It's mid skill range perk(60: 50% stamina regen) is better than the Heavy armor's mid range(50% less stagger from bieng hit).

Make sure you are fine with combat before putting perks into non-combat skills, as perks are important and will affect the difficulty of the game